# Fixing TF between base_link and odom

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, base-link, map-to-odom

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey , i am in the process of porting my robot from simulation to real world .

1. Finished URDF (robot_description) , which publishes the *tf*
2. Finished with the most essential stack such as robot_nav , robot_viz , robot_movebase

My Real Robot can now listen to cmd_vel and will responds correctly to it . I have written a script which accepts cmd_vel and publishes odom .

[image: image description]

**As you can see above the tf between odom and base_link is not yet published , what could be the reason for the same ?**

[image: image description]

"header:
seq: 40
stamp:
secs: 1517994494
nsecs: 929254055
frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
...."

[image: image description]

**As you can see the child_frame_id of the odom topic is base_link .**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282001/fixing-tf-between-base_link-and-odom/) by [chris_sunny](https://answers.ros.org/users/32569/chris_sunny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2018-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not sufficient, to publish this as an odometry Topic.
You Need to use a [tf broadcaster](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) to send the actual transformation via the tf tree.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_sunny](https://answers.ros.org/users/32569/chris_sunny/) on 2018-02-07**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/281781/ros-python-script-for-kangaroo-x2-sabertooth-2x32-configuration-accepts-cmd_vel-and-publishes-odom/  The python script which publishes odom is listed here  , please check it out . I believe i am using the tf_broadcaster ,let me know if i missed anything.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-07**:
Looks okay on a first glance. Do you see this transform in the tf message?